# Importing Tables from BigQuery to Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Dataflow pipeline (Apache Beam 2.1.0) that it first reads a table from BigQuery. (# of instances 4, instance type: n1-standard-16)

Here is the first pipeline w/ a table size: 
Estimated size      1.2 GB
BigQueryIO.Read/PassThroughThenCleanup/ParMultiDo(Identity).out0

**Job ID: 2017-10-20_12_27_11-78701910582961250**

[image]

Now, if I use a larger table:
[image]

Almost twice the size of the above-mentioned table:
Estimated size      2.27 GB

**JobID: 2017-10-18_16_43_55-10743775736175090102**

It takes much more. Basically, reading tables from BigQuery became the main bottleneck of my application. How can I tackle this performance bottleneck?

Comment: Simply put, you can't. No matter how many machines you throw at it, the pipeline is still dependant on the BigQuery export. Under the hood, Dataflow issues a export command to BigQuery to dump the table to GCS, and then it reads the data in parallel. The export from BigQuery is what is slowing things down, not the the actual read itself.

Comment: To look further in BigQuery side, if you can give the corresponding BigQuery export project + job ID that your dataflow jobs submitted, I can look into why the job was taking 56min. Although BigQuery doesn't provide any latency guarantee for exports, it usually takes less time to export ~2GB of data. Usually it's one of the following two reasons: (1) the system was busy at the time, or (2) the project has many extract jobs submitted around the same time, prolonging their queueing time.

Comment: Here is the project ID: gbsc-gcp-project-cba, and dataflow ID: 2017-10-18_16_43_55-10743775736175090102

Comment: Hi AmirCS, remember to add a @NhanNguyen in your reply comments so people you are referencing gets a notification in their Inbox

Comment: Thanks @WillianFuks!

Comment: @AmirCS, it's also the case that the 56m on the BigQuery read is the total amount of worker time, not the elapsed walltime - the actual job may take a similar total mount of time to execute.

The elapsed time is on the Developer's Console for the Dataflow job under the label "elapsed time"

Comment: +1 on what Thomas said. I looked it up and it looks like the associated BigQuery query & export jobs took only about 3-4 minutes to complete in total.

Comment: Thank you, @NhanNguyen. I understand that part, but is it always 3-4 mins? or does the execution time increase linearly based on the size of tables (more than ~2GB)? For this example, the size of tables is about 2GB, but it could be much much more. I mean is your solution for moving tables from BigQuery to Dataflow scalable? If not, then this would become the bottleneck of my application.

Comment: It depends. From what I see on the current state of the system, under 500GB it is fairly fast (under 10 minutes). From that point up, it usually increase linearly based on the data size (20 minutes for 1TB for instance). Of course the biggest factor as mentioned above is how many import/export jobs you have running concurrently on the project (as they all share the same resource pool).

Comment: @Nhan Nguyen: 500GB under 10 mins is good for now. Thanks for checking this out.